# File server for iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, google-app-engine, nsdata

I am working on an iOS app and have been stumped for the last few days trying to figure out how to set up a server to receive and serve data to the app. I have no experience with servers, which is making it difficult. I need to simply be able to upload and download NSData or plists (XML files). I looked into Google App Engine but got stumped. 
Could anyone provide some direction? I would truly appreciate it. This is the last major obstacle to completing the app I am working on.

Thank you

Comment: How did you "get stumped"? We can't help if we don't know what it is you're stuck on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend looking into [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/?tag=bucket-20). It is a simple file server that uses HTTP. Can't get much simpler than that, and does not require you to build anything server side.

Comment: Presumably the OP wants to be able to do access-control on a per-user basis, which is going to require more than just S3.